# Positioning students based on marks

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following code that retrieves a list of students and their marks for a particular subject.

```sql
                                                    
SELECT * 
FROM student_subject_averages 
where teaching_load_id IN (
    SELECT id 
    from teaching_loads 
    where teaching_loads.teacher_id=1573 AND subject_id=24 AND 
          teaching_loads.class_id IN (
               SELECT id 
               from grades 
               WHERE grades.stream_id=4))
```

How do I position the student according to their average in descending order?

I want the query to return the position of each child according to their mark

Comment: What column in `student_subject_averages` has the average? ... simply add `order by col` to the query. Replace `col` with the real column name.

Comment: Please share table structure with sample data. Also, share expected output from sample data.